# How do I right-align the 'help' menu item in CMFCMenuBar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

Using Visual Studio 2010 and creating standard MFC project with custom styles I have main menu items all aligned to left:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| File Edit Help                            |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
```

What do I need to do if I want the Help menu item on the right-hand side:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| File Edit                            Help |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                           |
```

I've tried different options in resource editor/properties for menu item, but haven't found anything that helped me to get the desired effect.

My current visual theme is Office 2007 - black, if it's relevant, but changing it I don't see it have any effect either.

Comment: Have you tired creating the menu dynamically by inserting each item individually?  You would need to insert "blank" items to right align the Help item.  Haven't tried it, but, seems like it should work.

Comment: `pMenu->ModifyMenu(nPos, MF_BYPOSITION | MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY, 0, szName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are talking about the new CMFCMenuBar than this feature is no longer available.

Also this style is no longer used in Microsoft products for years. Even in Windows XP the help menu was no longer right adjusted.

Internally I can still see a property named CMFCToolBarMenuButton::m_bShowAtRightSide but I don't see any location were it can be set.

Internally I checked the code that creates the CMFCMenuBar from the menu resource (CreateFromMenu). Also there is no code that checks for the MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY.